# How to get Validity Fingerprint Sensor working?

Tags: drivers, kubuntu, hp, fingerprint-reader

I have an HP Probook 640 G1 with a Valditity Sensors VFS495 Fingerprint reader.
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with KDE-Plasma Desktop Environment (Kubuntu). I can't seem to use the fingerprint sensor to unlock my device or even get it setup. I'm not sure what to do. I downloaded the drivers on HP's website. Here is the terminal output for when I was installing the driver and it seemed successful:

```
aaron@aaron-desktop:~/Downloads$ tar -xvf sp84530.tar
SP84530/
SP84530/Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm

aaron@aaron-desktop:~/Downloads$ cd SP84530/

aaron@aaron-desktop:~/Downloads/SP84530$ sudo alien -d Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5- 
136.0.x86_64.rpm
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
Warning: Skipping conversion of scripts in package SynapticsIncorporated: postinst 
postrm
Warning: Use the --scripts parameter to include the scripts.
warning: Validity-Sensor-Setup-4.5-136.0.x86_64.rpm: Header V4 DSA/SHA1 Signature, 
key ID 1c774eaa: NOKEY
synapticsincorporated_4.5-137_amd64.deb generated

aaron@aaron-desktop:~/Downloads/SP84530$ sudo dpkg -i synapticsincorporated_4.5- 
137_amd64.deb
(Reading database ... 306328 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack synapticsincorporated_4.5-137_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking synapticsincorporated (4.5-137) over (4.5-137) ...
Setting up synapticsincorporated (4.5-137) ...
```

Is there something I'm not doing or am missing. And there is no option in settings to setup fingerprints. Can someone help me get it working.
Here is the lsusb output:

```
aaron@aaron-desktop:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate 
Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate 
Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 05c8:0369 Cheng Uei Precision Industry 
Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP HD Webcam
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 138a:003f Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS495 
Fingerprint Reader
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 8087:07da Intel Corp. Centrino Bluetooth 
Wireless Transceiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And Here is lspci:

```
aaron@aaron-desktop:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen 
Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core 
Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen 
Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 
Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet 
Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #7 (rev d4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #8 (rev d4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM87 Express LPC Controller 
(rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series 
Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset 
Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 
6235 (rev 24)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** It appears that your fingerprint reader may not be supported. [Please review this site to confirm my observeration](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=usb:138a-003f&page=1#status). Also, to confirm your hardware device ID, please run `lsusb` (or `lspci`) and include the output in your question. We're looking specifically for the device ID of this reader to confirm (lack of) support. Thanks